# _itemFailedToPlayToEnd error when playing video in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video using `MPMoviePlayerController`, and am having following error,

```
 _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
   kind = 1;
   new = 2;
   old = 0;
  }
```

Below is my code,

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_videoUrl];
NSLog(@" fileURL: %@",fileURL);
_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
_moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayer play];
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What url are you trying to play? Is video in iOS supported format?

Comment: Adding to what Amar said, try to play that exact file from within the iOS Safari browser - if does not work, then you can be sure the format is not supported.

Comment: am getting this error when I am recording video in ios 7

Comment: is there any different method for recording ios7

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, viewed a lot of topics and haven't found working solution.
but what I have discovered that the problem with the url header response content type whose of your Movie URL..
if you try to SetContentUrl with another url from another server I guess this will solve the problem..